# Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. when running executable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am having some issues with a Spring configuration file. When attempting to use it, I get the message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 8 in XML document from file
>   [C:\WORK\Software\SOAPUI\extract-rest-with-crud\productws\target\classes\WEB-INF\dbcontext.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 74; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the
>   declaration of element 'beans'.

Below is the Spring configuration file. What exactly is the problem?

TIA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:hibernate.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactorybean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.apostx.ccfd.master.entities" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.isolation">${hibernate.isolation}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">${hibernate.current_session_context_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">${hibernate.transaction.factory_class}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like this fixed the problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```